# Subquery returning wrong answer

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two tables like
1:-Users

```
id  name
1   vivek
2   raj
3   mohan
4   gagan
5   priya
```

2:-Purchase

```
id  typee        user_id
1   class        1
2   class        1
3   course       1
4   class        2
5   test_series  3
6   test_series  2
```

I am trying to run

```
select p.id,(select count(purchasee.user_id) as tot
             from purchasee
             where purchasee.user_id=p.id
             and typee='class'
             or typee='course' ) as classcourse,(select count(purchasee.user_id) as tot
                                                 from purchasee
                                                 where purchasee.user_id=p.id 
                                                 and typee='test_series') as test 
from purchasee as p
GROUP by p.user_id
```

query and its ginving me

```
id      Classcourse    test
1       3              0
4       1              0
5       0              1
```

expected answer is

```
id      Classcourse    test
1       3              0
4       1              1
5       0              1
```

I want to select the user purchase the (class or course) or (test_series) if yes user purchase class or course then count it or if user purchase test_series then count the number of rows

Comment: May you please explain our logic a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

try below sql

```
SELECT p.id,
     SUM( IF( typeee = 'class' || typeee = 'course', 1,0) ) as tot,
     SUM( IF (typeee = 'test_series', 1,0) ) as classcourse
FROM purchasee as p
GROUP by p.user_id
```